# Error while getting values from DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, groovy, sql-server-2012

I want to get values from SQL Server by Groovy.

```
Sql.withInstance("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost;instance=SQLEXPRESS;",
           'login',
           'password',
           'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource') {
    it.execute("use Base")
    it.rows("select * from table") {
        List val = it.values()                 
    }
...
}
```

Method `rows()` should return `List<GroovyRowResult>`, but I have:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:  net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSetMetaData.get() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

What am I doing wrong and how can I get values from database?

Comment: On which line does that exception get thrown?

Answer (score 1):

Because when you use  List val = it.values() , the "it" is mean [JtdsResultSetMetaData](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/doc/net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/JtdsResultSetMetaData.htm) . that is not your expect ResultSet and JtdsResultSetMetaData do not have values() method so will get exception. you can use this code try get your ResultSet

```
    Sql.withInstance("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost;instance=SQLEXPRESS;",
           'login',
           'password',
           'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource') {
    it.execute("use Base")
    List val = it.rows("SELECT * FROM table")
    print val
...
}
```